# Not able to get rid of namespace while extracting infromation from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have been facing problem while extracting information from an XML using XSLT. Namespace is also appearing in the output which is not acceptable.

The XML I recieve from another system

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>  
        <ns1:DeptResponse xmlns:ns1="http://samplecomp.com" xmlns="http://mycomp.org">
            <Department>
                <Building bid="b_1579">
                <DeptName>Sports</DeptName>
                <DeptHead>
                    <Person pid="123">
                        <Name>David Shephard</Name>
                        <Address>
                            <Street>Test</Street>
                            <State code="18">Georgia</State>            
                        </Address>              
                    </Person>
                </DeptHead>
                <DeptYear>1925</DeptYear>
            </Department>
        </ns1:DeptResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My XSL to etract required information from the above xml:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"      
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
    xmlns:ns1="http://samplecomp.com" 
    xmlns:dept="http://mycomp.org"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 xsl dept">  

    <xsl:template match="/">         
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//dept:Person"/>     
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">        
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no"  >             
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>        
        </xsl:copy>    
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The response I recieved after XSL: 
The response contaitn a xmlns:="http://myccomp.org"  which I want to get rid of. I have tried using the copy-namespaces="no"  but of no use. :(

```
<Person xmlns="http://mycomp.org" pid="123">
    <Name>David Shephard</Name>
    <Address>
        <Street>Test</Street>
        <State code="18">Georgia</State>            
    </Address>
</Person>
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:copy` will include the namespaces bound to that element. `copy-namespaces="no"` will only exclude extraneous namespaces from the document that are not used in the context element being copied.

If you want to create an element(or attribute) that is not bound to a namespace in your output, you will need to re-constitute an element using `xsl:element` and new attribute using `xsl:attribute` with their `local-name()` as the @name:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"      
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
    xmlns:ns1="http://samplecomp.com" 
    xmlns:dept="http://mycomp.org"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 xsl dept">  

    <xsl:template match="/">         
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//dept:Person"/>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">        
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">             
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>        
        </xsl:element>    
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="@*">        
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}" select="." />  
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="text()|processing-instruction()|comment()">        
        <xsl:copy>             
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>        
        </xsl:copy>    
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. But I didn't understand why the text() was added.

Comment: I added `text()` to be explicit and show that template was handling all of the other items normally matched by `node()`, now that there was a separate template for `*`. You could leave it out it would still work, because the built-in/default templates would copy `text()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
    xmlns:ns1="http://samplecomp.com" 
    xmlns:dept="http://mycomp.org"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns1 xsl dept">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
   <xsl:template match="/">         
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//dept:Person"/>     
    </xsl:template>   
     <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well if you use `xsl:copy` you create a copy of the context node, in the case of an element that means you create an element with the same name and the name consists of the namespace and the local name. `copy-namespaces="no"` only helps not to copy any other in scope namespacees but it doesn't change the name of the element to be copied. So in your case what you want is to transform the elements from a certain namespace into ones with the same local name but in no namespace i.e.

```
<xsl:template match="dept:*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```